# Chrome Android remote devtools inspector returns a 404

Tags: android, google-chrome

When I'm trying to inspect remove cordova App using android remove devtools , it returns me HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

URL loaded is

chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@....../inspector.html?remoteFrontend=true

https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/@180870/devtools.html
works
https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/@180870/inspector.html not

maybe linked to the problem...

Chrome is up to date, reproduced on many computers.

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Developer Tools : Android Debugging returns HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519636/google-chrome-developer-tools-android-debugging-returns-http-1-1-404-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem. Latest Chrome version is buggy. Disabling chrome on my android phone was the only thing that worked for me. Your phone will instead use the webview version it shipped with (58 in my case). Sure problem will be resolved soon at which point you can reinstall chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.
Ensure your android chrome version is *newer* than your computer's. (For example, I use windows chrome 85 and android chrome 86dev)
Then there will be a `inspect fallback` option at the `chrome://inspect/#devices` page. You can just click it and use the fallback inspect.
[image: my screenshot]
It works for me.