# Chrome DevTools Remote Debugging Does Not Display Connected Mobile Devices' chrome version

Tags: android, ruby, localhost, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to remotely debug through my ruby localhost through the chrome development tools, and although I have established a connection to the USB connected device, the chrome version of the mobile browser is not displaying.

Without that I'm unable to debug. What could be missing? I have already installed the necessary drivers to make the PC to mobile connection

[image: Screen shot of my development tools]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the workaround in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519636/google-chrome-developer-tools-android-debugging-returns-http-1-1-404-not-found).

> Solution was to access through chrome://inspect/#devices
>
> Then select the "Fallback" option.
>
> This is because the remote browser was newer than the client browser……

While the PC is connected to the device via USB with the app open, go to `chrome://inspect/#devices` on the PC. You should see the name of the app and an "inspect fallback" link