# How to debug apps on an AVD via a browser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, remote-debugging

I am new to coding web apps on Android,  and I don't know how to debug apps running in an emulator via a browser.  This page: [Remote debug Android apps](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) suggests that to debug apps remotely, you need to connect your Android device via USB to the remote system. I am confused as to how to achieve this with an AVD. Has anyone got any answers??

**Edit:**

I actually posted this question as I was getting  "HTTP/1.1 404 not found" whenever I run chrome://inspect/#devices for an AVD, but I  wasn't getting same error whenever I run it through my Android device.

However, currently I have found an [SO question addressing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519636/google-chrome-developer-tools-android-debugging-returns-http-1-1-404-not-found)

Comment: What do you mean by "remotely debug apps running in an emulator"? Can you edit your question and explain a bit more about your environment?

Comment: I want to view debug/log info of the code running in WebVeiw through a chrome console, as if I  connected a physical device via USB to my system for debugging

Comment: That is reasonable, but, that is not remote debugging, at least in terms of how the Android SDK documentation will use the term.

Comment: Oh OK. What is the right term

Comment: I would just call it "debugging". It is possible that Apache Cordova uses different terms, and since you have your question tagged `cordova`, I am assuming that you are using Cordova. I have not used Cordova in several years, so I am not up to date on its terminology.

Comment: Have you tried chrome://inspect ?

Comment: @Eric, I retried it and now it works, its because I was unaware that inspect requires an internet connection. I just noticed it, thanks